# How to drop a pandas dataframe after storing in database

Tags: python, pandas

How do I drop a pandas dataframes after I store them in a database. I can only find a way to drop columns or rows from a dataframe but how can I drop a complete data frame to free my computer memory?

Comment: Isn't it dropped automatically when reaching the end of its scope? If it has global scope, I guess you could use `del()`

Comment: Yip. Delete it before the GC gets it.

Answer (score 4):

`del dataframe` will unpollute your namespace and free your memory, while `dataframe = None` will only free your memory. Hope that helps!